# Arraylist inside arraylist, how do I clear the last

Tags: java, arraylist

I use while loop to read a text file and create new arraylists out of portions of the text file and then place those arraylists inside another arraylist. My problem is that I don't know how to add my temporary arraylist parse into the mainAList and then clear it for the next loop without affecting all the parse arraylists inside the arraylist<arraylist> mainAList. More info inside the comments below in the code.

This is a sample code, it is from larger file. It is shortened but has all the moving parts

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mainAList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> parse = new ArrayList<>();

try (Scanner filereader = new Scanner(Paths.get("name_of_file.txt"))) {
    while (filereader.hasNextLine()) {
        parse.add(filereader.nextLine());
        if (parse.get(parse.size()-1).length() == 0 || !filereader.hasNextLine()) {
            // if the file reader detects empty line or has no more lines
            //  the arraylist called parse gets added to the mainAList
            mainAList.add(parse);
        }
        parse.clear();
        // here is my problem. How do I clear parse so for the next patch of lines
         //  so I don't add the same things + more into the next slot of mainAList
         // every time the loop runs?
         // I understand my issue is not how to correctly clear the parse but 
         // how to add the arraylists correctly into the mainAList so I can alter them individually
   }
}
```

The file that is read is like this:
a
b
c
d

f
g

h
i
j
k
l

etc..

Comment: Try doing `mainAList.add(parse.copy())` instead, so you add a _copy_ of the list instead of adding the list itself multiple times. That, or move the line where you create `parse` inside the `while` loop so that it makes a new one every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your current approach:

1. `parse` will use the same reference for all inner ArrayLists, so when you call `parse.clear()` it will empty all inner lists of your `mainAList`. This can be solved by creating a copy of the `parse` list when you add it (i.e. `mainAList.add(new ArrayList<>(parse));`)
2. You want to clear the list inside the if as well, after you've added the copy to your `mainAList`.

In addition, I assume you don't want the empty lines added to the individual inner Lists, so you could read the line first, and either add the entire list to `mainAList` and clear `parse` inside the if-statement, or add the line to the `parse`-list.

A slightly better alternative, is to just create a new list instead, so you won't need the `clear` and creating a copy of the list.

In total:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mainAList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> parse = new ArrayList<>();

try (Scanner filereader = new Scanner(System.in)) {
  while (filereader.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = filereader.nextLine();
    if (line.length() == 0 || !filereader.hasNextLine()) {
        // if the file reader detects empty line or has no more lines
        // the arraylist called parse gets added to the mainAList
        mainAList.add(parse);
        // and then a new parse-list is created for the next group of inputs:
        parse = new ArrayList<>();
    } else{
        parse.add(line);
    }
  }
}
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##jVI7T@QwEO79Kz465yQC9e0tEj3QbImuMMkk8eLYkT2BW8H@9j3bCSGAhHBja@Z7zMN79aTO9/Xj6aT7wXnGPgbKkbUpf21EZVQIuFXavghgGB@MrhBYcbyenK7Rx5Tcsde2vf8LVSQYcO29OtzowH/eXxPo6ipTrlMIW1h6/hYsi80nwTmDQflAXxQyITPYHyB3lbKWPBptyJOq43NizAm5OwSmvtS2KDCVDjx3EQ35zik7Fe7oH99oS3IFBKZiYGIiCq8YdoFvFrBuIBOyNGRb7mSB7RaXeH3F2U@80rm4SCrcUfbC3FJNTBUHUD/wYSrGeUQhWIfeecqx8Fkp66g0OpOWUSljqJ7n2lLUU3UdA@wycNnaB5klWkawzNxVx7ORsnWSsFB59hl1nj11QBWb4GjTxJKTT5ocWu/GAa6BtsPI4fcHxW82/wY5gkygl6@0XGaaxhos1vdx@j7zx3Ajl0PcMRsrl14z9yiOp5MSD6IStRCNaIXohBZ78SjMfw)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of clearing the list everytime.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mainAList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

try (Scanner filereader = new Scanner(Paths.get("name_of_file.txt"))) {
    while (filereader.hasNextLine()) {
        ArrayList<String> parse = new ArrayList<>();
        parse.add(filereader.nextLine());
        if (parse.get(parse.size()-1).length() == 0 || !filereader.hasNextLine()) {
         mainAList.add(parse);
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `mainAList` will be empty in the end because objects are reference types. In order to fix that problem, you have to add a copy of `parse` to the `mainAList` and not the `parse` arraylist itself

replace this line

```
mainAList.add(parse);
```

with this

```
mainAList.add(new ArrayList<>(parse));
```